# What does BIOS do after loading Global/Interrupt Descriptor Table Register in JOS?

Tags: operating-system, bios

I have analyzed the very first codes when BIOS starts executing until loading Global/Interrupt Descriptor Table Register. The BIOS I'm talking about is the one from MITs course "Operating Systems Engineering". I have difficulities understanding how BIOS do after that.

```
[f000:fff0]    0xffff0: ljmp   $0xf000,$0xe05b
#when BIOS starts executing, jump to the address fe05bH to continue to execute
[f000:e05b]    0xfe05b: cmpl   $0x0,%cs:0x6574
[f000:e062]    0xfe062: jne    0xfd2b6
[f000:e066]    0xfe066: xor    %ax,%ax
[f000:e068]    0xfe068: mov    %ax,%ss
#set %ss to 0
[f000:e06a]    0xfe06a: mov    $0x7000,%esp
[f000:e070]    0xfe070: mov    $0xf3c24,%edx
[f000:e076]    0xfe076: jmp    0xfd124
[f000:d124]    0xfd124: mov    %eax,%ecx
[f000:d127]    0xfd127: cli
#turn off interrupt
[f000:d128]    0xfd128: cld 
# set DF flag to 0, when  DF=0, SI = SI + 1 , DI = DI + 1
[f000:d129]    0xfd129: mov    $0x8f,%eax
[f000:d12f]    0xfd12f: out    %al,$0x70
[f000:d131]    0xfd131: in     $0x71,%al
#close NMI through 70H I/O port, selecting CMOS 0xF register, and assigining 0xF register's value to %al register
[f000:d133]    0xfd133: in     $0x92,%al
[f000:d135]    0xfd135: or     $0x2,%al
[f000:d137]    0xfd137: out    %al,$0x92
#enable A20 address line
[f000:d139]    0xfd139: lidtw  %cs:0x6690
[f000:d13f]    0xfd13f: lgdtw  %cs:0x6650
#loading Global/Interrupt Descriptor Table Register
[f000:d145]    0xfd145: mov    %cr0,%eax
[f000:d148]    0xfd148: or     $0x1,%eax
[f000:d14c]    0xfd14c: mov    %eax,%cr0
#set CR0 PE=1. when PE=1 CPU is in protected mode
[f000:d14f]    0xfd14f: ljmpl  $0x8,$0xfd157
 The target architecture is assumed to be i386
 => 0xfd157:    mov    $0x10,%eax
 => 0xfd15c:    mov    %eax,%ds
 => 0xfd15e:    mov    %eax,%es
 => 0xfd160:    mov    %eax,%ss
 => 0xfd162:    mov    %eax,%fs
 => 0xfd164:    mov    %eax,%gs
 #After loading GDTR, it's necessary to reload all the segment register
 .....
```

After these codes, I don't know how BIOS executes to search for a bootable device such as a floppy, hard drive, or CD-ROM. Eventually, when it finds a bootable disk, the BIOS reads the boot loader from the disk and transfers control to it

Answer (score 0):

super late response but I was having the same question and found the answer in the [SeaBIOS source code](https://github.com/coreboot/seabios/blob/master/src/romlayout.S)

The page I linked is the source code for the vector mapped to the reset vector.
If you really want to parse through the 40 kilobytes of BIOS code in GDB, feel free to grab some scratch paper and start mapping out the stack layout and BIOS code layout.  I spent a few hours doing that before deciding to read the source code instead; it's probably healthier to read the source code.

EDIT:  also check out [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS#Extensions_.28option_ROMs.29) on the wikipedia page for BIOS on option ROMs, gives better info on option ROMs than the wikipedia page for option ROMs. Took forever to figure that out.